# How do you toggle a class in jquery when label element is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. When the checkbox is checked (which is hidden), when the label is pressed around the avatar, I want to add a class "selected" to the outer div (pop-friends-item).

```
<div class="pop-friends-item">
    <label for="user_1" class="check_friend_item">
    <input name="invited[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="user_1" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/avatar.jpg"> User 1</label>
</div>
<div class="pop-friends-item">
    <label for="user_2" class="check_friend_item">
    <input name="invited[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="user_2" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/avatar.jpg"> user 2</label>
</div>
```

I only got it to add the class to all the items, not just the one thats clicked.

Comment: Sidenote: the id attribute for your inputs are invalid. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("label.check_friend_item").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div.pop-friends-item").toggleClass("selected");
    var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        $checkbox.attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $checkbox.attr('checked', true);
    }
};
```

The whole checkbox shebang is probably not necessary if you can use valid HTML, though.

[Link to JsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/FRM4A/4)

Comment: Removing the ID from the checkbox makes the toggle work, but then the checkbox doesn't actually get chcecked when the label is clicked. Adding the ID makes the checkbox work, but the toggle does not.

Comment: Used a valid ID, had no effect. Moving the checkbox outside of the <label></label> seemed to have solved everything.

Comment: @Yegor Ah, then it was probably invalid HTML. Nice going

Answer (score 1):

This just sets the `selected` class.

```
$("label").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").addClass("selected");
};
```

If you want to toggle back and forth:

```
$("label").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("selected");
};
```

**UPDATE**

Here's an update to handle the checkbox toggle (set to display)
http://jsfiddle.net/qqUHW/1/

```
$("label").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("div").toggleClass("selected");
    var $checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox']", $this);
    if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
        $checkbox.prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $checkbox.prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest using `$(this).closest("div")` instead of `$(this).parents("div")`.

Comment: It seems to run twice every time I click it, so it toggles back to nothing.

Comment: @bfavaretto - agreed... typed too quickly!

Comment: Yah it seems every click I make to this, actually does 2 clicks, so it toggles it on, and off.

Comment: Was the ID on the checbox. Thanks

Comment: But now, it doesn't check the checkbox when the label is clicked :(

Answer (score 0):

this should do it without the checkbox, if the `pop-friends-item` is always the direct parent of the label

```
$("label").click(function(){

   $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

});
```

if more than one needs selected then this should also work

```
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
```

---

As an alternative, to actually do it using the checkboxes, a [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function could be used, and you would need to hide the checkboxes in a more accessible way:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.pop-friends-item input').change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('div').addClass("selected");
   } else {
      $(this).closest('div').removeClass("selected");
   }
});
```

**CSS** to hide the input instead of `display: none;`:

```
.pop-friends-item input {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
   clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
}
```

Comment: That's assuming he only wants one selected at a time.

Comment: @Paul; indeed, thanks I updated with the select more/toggle to cancel :D

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you're just adding the class to the correct div, limit your selector a bit more by adding the class of the div.

```
$("label.check_friend_item").click(function() {
      $(this).parents("div.pop-friends-item").toggleClass("selected");
});
```